# Ending imap-simple connection within recursion

Tags: javascript, imap, nightwatch.js

I currently have a script that checks for an incoming email (in a mailbox) every 30 seconds, using a recursion.

The package I'm using for this testing is [imap-simple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap-simple).

The below script currently does this as required;

```
var imaps = require('imap-simple');
const { connect } = require('net');
var config = {
    imap: {
        user: 'qatestspecialist@outlook.com',
        password: 'specialistQa',
        host: 'imap-mail.outlook.com',
        port: 993,
        tls: true,
        authTimeout: 30000
    }
};

module.exports = {

    'delete any existing emails...': function () {
        imaps.connect(config).then(function (connection) {
            connection.openBox('INBOX').then(function () {
                var searchCriteria = ['ALL'];
                var fetchOptions = { bodies: ['TEXT'], struct: true };
                return connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions);
            //Loop over each message
            }).then(function (messages) {
                let taskList = messages.map(function (message) {
                    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                        var parts = imaps.getParts(message.attributes.struct);
                        parts.map(function (part) {
                            return connection.getPartData(message, part)
                            .then(function (partData) {
                                //Display e-mail body
                                if (part.disposition == null && part.encoding != "base64"){
                                    console.log(partData);
                                }
                                //Mark message for deletion
                                connection.addFlags(message.attributes.uid, "\Deleted", (err) => {
                                    if (err){
                                        console.log('Problem marking message for deletion');
                                        rej(err);
                                    }
                                    res(); //Final resolve
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
                return Promise.all(taskList).then(() => {
                    connection.imap.closeBox(true, (err) => { //Pass in false to avoid delete-flagged messages being removed
                        if (err){
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    });
                    connection.end();
                });
            });
        });
    },

    'send email to seller and wait for mailbox notification': function (browser) {
        // script to send an email to the mailbox...
    },

    'get new email info': function(browser) {
        const createPromise = ms => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => resolve(ms), ms)
            });
            function findUnseenEmails(connection) {
                return connection.openBox('INBOX').then(function () {
                    var searchCriteria = ['UNSEEN'];
                    var fetchOptions = {
                        bodies: ['HEADER', 'TEXT'],
                        markSeen: false
                    };
                    return connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions).then(function (results) {
                        var subjects = results.map(function (res) {
                            return res.parts.filter(function (part) {
                                return part.which === 'HEADER';
                            })
                            [0].body.subject[0];
                        });
                        return subjects.length > 0 ? subjects : createPromise(30000).then(function() { return findUnseenEmails(connection);
                    });
                });
            });
        }

        imaps.connect(config).then(function (connection) {
            return findUnseenEmails(connection)
        })

        .then((subjects) => console.log(JSON.stringify(subjects)));
    },

    'Closing the browser': function (browser) {
        browser.browserEnd();
    }

};
```

This waits for an email and then displays the email 'header'.

However, the imap connection does not close, and stays open which is stopping my test suite from completing as the associated test never actually finishes.

I've tried adding the imap-simple command `connection.end()` in several places after the

```
imaps.connect(config).then(function (connection) {
     return findUnseenEmails(connection)
})
```

part of the script, but it doesn't work.

So I'm just wondering if anyone knows where I should be adding this `connection.end()` command in order for the connection to be closed **once an email has been received**?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been resolved in another post, using the following;

```
if (subjects.length > 0) {
    connection.end();
    return subjects;
} else {
    return createPromise(5000).then(function() { return findUnseenEmails(connection)});
}
```